# My RPi2 became very slow suddenly

Tags: pi-2, performance

I am running Raspbian on my RPi2 and on top of that a Node.js server.

This morning the Node.js server went down, but I still have access to the SSH terminal.

I ran `top` but couldn't see any processes using huge amount of resources. Instead, I noticed that for any command I am running, I have to wait quite a lot (e.g. `top`, `free`, `vim`, `tmux` etc).

I don't think that writing/reading from the disk is the issue because that is actually fast (`touch foo > bar` just works fine, and directory commands like `ls` are fast).

What could be the issue?

###### Relevant output

```
[11730.424403] [fae1fb59] CMD  11 200
[11730.424414] [fae1fb59] REQ> 81f6e2a8 0
[11730.424425] [fb7e2e2c] TIM< 0 0
[11730.424445] mmc0: cmd op 17 arg 0xa2a096 flags 0xb5 - resp 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000, err 0
[11730.424457] mmc0: data blocks 1 blksz 200 - err 0
[11730.424466] mmc0: =========== REGISTER DUMP ===========
[11730.424476] mmc0: SDCMD  0x00004051
[11730.424485] mmc0: SDARG  0x00a2a096
[11730.424495] mmc0: SDTOUT 0x017d7840
[11730.424503] mmc0: SDCDIV 0x00000003
[11730.424512] mmc0: SDRSP0 0x00000900
[11730.424522] mmc0: SDRSP1 0x00001133
[11730.424531] mmc0: SDRSP2 0x7fffffff
[11730.424540] mmc0: SDRSP3 0x08024016
[11730.424549] mmc0: SDHSTS 0x00000080
[11730.424558] mmc0: SDVDD  0x00000001
[11730.424567] mmc0: SDEDM  0x00010801
[11730.424576] mmc0: SDHCFG 0x0000041e
[11730.424586] mmc0: SDHBCT 0x00000200
[11730.424595] mmc0: SDHBLC 0x00000001
[11730.424603] mmc0: ===========================================
[11730.431815] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 10657942 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[11740.661554] mmc0: timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
...
[11740.664385] [fb7e5688] CMD  11 200
[11740.664396] [fb7e5688] REQ> 81f6e2a8 0
[11740.664407] [fc1a6e3a] TIM< 0 0
[11740.664427] mmc0: cmd op 17 arg 0xa2a097 flags 0xb5 - resp 00000900 00000000 00000000 00000000, err 0
[11740.664440] mmc0: data blocks 1 blksz 200 - err 0
[11740.664449] mmc0: =========== REGISTER DUMP ===========
[11740.664459] mmc0: SDCMD  0x00004051
[11740.664468] mmc0: SDARG  0x00a2a097
[11740.664478] mmc0: SDTOUT 0x017d7840
[11740.664487] mmc0: SDCDIV 0x00000003
[11740.664496] mmc0: SDRSP0 0x00000900
[11740.664505] mmc0: SDRSP1 0x00001133
[11740.664515] mmc0: SDRSP2 0x7fffffff
[11740.664524] mmc0: SDRSP3 0x08024016
[11740.664532] mmc0: SDHSTS 0x00000080
[11740.664541] mmc0: SDVDD  0x00000001
[11740.664551] mmc0: SDEDM  0x00010801
[11740.664560] mmc0: SDHCFG 0x0000041e
[11740.664569] mmc0: SDHBCT 0x00000200
[11740.664578] mmc0: SDHBLC 0x00000001
[11740.664587] mmc0: ===========================================
[11740.669944] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 10657943 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
```

Comment: Despite what you've said, I'd suspect the SD card is "worn" - check `dmesg` output - I take it you've done a reboot - what's your load average look like?

Comment: @Bravo Yesterday there were many electricity interruptions... Maybe that caused it to break...? I did a reboot, and it is now stuck at the black screen (after the Raspbian Logo desktop).

Comment: oh - did you check the logs before rebooting?

Comment: @Bravo Umm, no, but now it responds to `ping` and the SSH verbose seems to do something, but it is terribly slow. This RPi2 broke multiple micro SD cards from Kingston – is there I could do to avoid that? Honestly, in my experience with Raspberry Pi, I always had the impression the entire system is quite fragile... :-(

Comment: Did you try restoring from your backup?

Comment: @Milliways I don't do regular backups for his device, but instead store the apps on GitHub...

Comment: @Bravo I added the `dmesg` output... Something seems fishy indeed. I am not sure if it can be _repaired_ using some kind of cli tool...

Comment: I'd try a new sd card

Comment: Have you checked the temperature?

Comment: Well, it has 42'C, but again, the command was very slow.

Comment: Based on the kernel error I think the card is probably physically damaged.  Salvage whatever data you want/can from it and replace.  *Unless* you notice any `Under-voltage` warnings in the logs during the same time frame, that can cause I/O failures.

Comment: @goldilocks For reference, I was getting _Under-voltage_ always for this RPi2 (specifically that zap icon on the top right corner of the display which I recently found out what it actually means). Could the under-voltage supply and the electricity interruptions damage the micro SD card? I am thinking to add an UPS for the router and the pi, hence getting a minimal downtime for the pi – would that help? I just assume the sudden shutdowns (due to the electricity interruptions) are not so friendly.

Comment: The micro SD card was unreadable on Windows, but Ubuntu can read it just fine. I just put a brand new card in the pi and I am configuring it again.

Comment: I think it should not happen easily (ie., not every power cut will damage a card) but it cannot be called impossible either, and depends on the quality of the supply (if, eg, it produces momentary surges with cuts, this might be an issue with the mains too I think).  If you can get the Pi (or a Pi) to run with a stable power supply you could confirm whether it is a problem with the card.

Comment: @goldilocks Just for the record, Ubuntu cannot read the `~/.pm2/` directory where I have the application logs –– I assume that these were open streams where it would keep logging data in those text files and when the electrcitiy interrupts, that could possible create bad sectors on the card (in a similar manner like when ejecting the card when copying something to it).

Comment: Just to be clear:  That error isn't due to corrupted sectors (which you can get cutting power regardless of the source quality).   It's a hardware problem.  Corruption is just a filesystem/data problem.  It may make your system unusable, but it is relatively easy to fix.  To elaborate: Reading corrupted data is the same at a hardware level as reading uncorrupted data: It doesn't matter what the data is or isn't content wise (including bad content = corrupted).  It won't produce those kinds of low level I/O errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other answers are good, I think the root problem here was the electric interruptions that happen quite often, especially when there are thunderstorms, which made the pi to force restart every time.

By shutting down like that, the microSD card got corrupted.

To prevent this, I set up an UPS device between the power outlet and the pi, so when the electricity goes down, the power to the device is *not* interrupted.

I have to devices set up this way, in two different locations and got uptimes of 69 and 75 days, as of today, which is something quite good I must say.

Also, after two months I do not see any problems with the file system which is great.

---

**TL;DR:** If the electricity powering the pi is unstable, an UPS device may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you check that your CPU heat sink is still well-attached.  Sometimes overheating will slow things down although they are still marginally functional.  For example, simple command line functions like ping and ssh are the last to remain working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with RPI2, RPI3 and RP zero also.
Your SD card died. Initially, your file system corrupted, funfact, you can't detect it. You can use fsck and forcefully check and repair it, that could help at least for saving out everything from it. You can try to format/partition it again and use it (it worked for me 7 times from 10).
your SD card has worned out memory blocks, what is ~physical damage, you will have data loss.

What lead to that:

- Faulty factored SD card
- Voltage changes (under-over electricity)
- multiple random turn off while it working (sometime even one power off time is enough, sometime good for hundreds)
- constant overheat
- Too many write on the SD card

PM2 and nodejs write a lot (at least on cache level) and uses a bunch of files. Probably you have quite a lots of log file also.
I had the same setup ;) and had the same issue. I replaced the first sandisk card, the second one working like charm ~3 years now.

My advice:

- Minimalize the log usage or generic writing to the SD card
- Try to use SSD/HDD if its an option
- Try to minimalize the NODE js dependency blackhole (e.g.: node_modules)
- Use pro/industrial tier SD card (could be quite expensive)
- Use stable power (afaik rpi does not have any regulator)
- Turn off the desktop view if you don't need it to save power
- Check the SoC/CPU for heat, add a passive heatsink to it (super cheap usually), if you have it, then check the pasta/contact.

What you can do right now:

- Backup what you can, partition then format the card, install never rpi os, then use it again until it does not tear down
- Use a different card
- Use harddrive or ssd
- Set up some backup policy